# Jenkins P4_CHANGELIST variable is "now"?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I have a Jenkins pipeline to produce a nightly build. It is configured to use a pipeline script from SCM, in our case Perforce. I would like to use the latest changelist in the pipeline scripts, and have tried using P4_CHANGELIST, like so:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        [...]
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo "Nightly Build ${P4_CHANGELIST}: Success"
        }
    }
}
```

According to the documentation at https://www.perforce.com/manuals/jenkins/Content/P4Jenkins/variable-expansion.html the P4_CHANGELIST variable should contain

> The last Perforce changelist number included in the populated workspace.

However, it appears to contain "now".

Id this a bug, since it doesn't match what the documentation says? Does it happen because the pipeline was not triggered by a specific change, but on a schedule? Are there other ways to get the latest changelist?

Comment: Perforce accepts `@now` as a revision specifier in most places where `@CHANGE` is accepted, including the `sync` command.  However I'd generally recommend against using that in your build pipeline because then you don't have any record of what `@now` meant at the time you synced to do the build.

Comment: I'm not the one using it in my build pipeline. It's the plugin, when configuring a pipeline to run periodically or starting a build via the "build now" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a reported bug with periodic builds and the "Build Now" button. There is a workaround documented in https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-70437 : Use the build trigger 'Poll SCM' instead of 'Build periodically'.